# find net use with batch

Tags: networking, batch-file, net-use

Hi just wanted to know if its possible to create a txt file listing all net use path

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
net use > c:\netusepaths.txt
```

and that will give you the paths in a text file (just pick the filename and location you want).

If you want just the lines with the paths on (rather than the whole output of net use) try

```
net use | find "OK" > c:\netusepaths.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
net use > c:\temp\test.txt
```